# C++ Boost.Thread: Passing a method of an object

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-thread

Given object x, I'd like to launch a new thread to invoke `x.a()` or even `x.a(1,2,3)`.  I can use `boost::thread` to do this for a non-member function; but how do I do this for a member function? How do I pass the `this` pointer?

In general, there's lots of STL and Boost code and templates which take code as a parameter, but, as this is not really defined in C++ (functions aren't first class vals, no native lambda support), I'm very confused how they're defined.  I can do trial and error but I'd like something cleaerer and more reliable.

**UPDATE:** My question concerns primarily passing a method; when I try to do what would be the obvious syntax  `(ClassName::method_name, instance)`  I get `invalid use of non-static member function` `error: no matching function to call`.  It would help if you could show the proper syntax to use Boost.thread on a non-static method.

**UPDATE 2**: I found why I'm struggling with this.  The answers given, such as by @OrDinari, work great for `boost::thread`.  But, when I try using a `thread_group`, that is, `thread_group::create_thread`, I get this error:

```
 error: no matching function for call to ‘boost::thread_group::create_thread(void (C::*)(), C*)’
```

So:

1. Why does it work for single threads but not thread groups?
2. How do I use create a thread in a group to run a member function?

Comment: C++ does have native lambda support.

Comment: You could also use boost::bind if you're a primitive savage.

Comment: This has been answered a million times on StackOverflow

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, why would you use `bind`? What's wrong with simply `thread t(&X::a, &x, 1, 2, 3)` ?

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example:

```
        boost::thread _commandControl(&Client::commandControl, &client);
```

This create a new thread, using the client object method commandControl, from the Client instance named client.

and here a bit larger piece of the code, might be easier to understand:

```
Client client(host, port);
std::cout << "Pick interface (1) Terminal  (2) Menu:\n";
char interfaceMode;
std::cin >> interfaceMode;
while (!client.setMode(interfaceMode)) {
    std::cout << "\nInvalid choice! try again (1) For Terminal  (2)For Menu:";
    std::cin >> interfaceMode;
}
try {
    std::cin.ignore();
    if (client.connect()) {
        try {

            boost::thread _commandControl(&Client::commandControl, &client);
            boost::thread _checkQueue(&Client::checkQueue, &client);
            _checkQueue.join();
            if (client.checkAlive() == false)throw ConnectionDCexception();
            _commandControl.join();
            client.close();
        }
        catch (std::exception &e) {
            std::cout << "\n" << e.what();
        }
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "\nFailed to initiate connecting, exiting...";
    }
}
```

The main thing you are looking for is:

```
Client client(host, port);

boost::thread _commandControl(&Client::commandControl, &client);
boost::thread _checkQueue(&Client::checkQueue, &client);
```

each is a different thread, from the same instance (client) of the class Client.

Comment: Thanks - please see update that this fails for thread_group.  Can you take a look?

Answer (score 0):

If you use C++11, you can use lambdas:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

class Foo
{
public:
    void foo()
    {
        std::cout << "Foo thread: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::cout << "Main thred: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;

    Foo foo;
    std::thread t1( [&foo] () {foo.foo();} );
    t1.join();

    return 0;
}
```

You can replace std::thread to boost::thread.